# Meaning of commit date in git log

Tags: git, git-log

When I check the master log in git doing:

```
git log master -30 --pretty="%h - %s - %cn - %cd"
```

And I see:

```
...
af79643 - BL - added changes from test fix - B Lo - Fri Nov 15 12:04:42 2013 +0000
...
```

Does this mean that on Friday 15 Nov this was checked into master or could it mean that this commit was checked into somewhere else (e.g. develop) and then subsequently merged into master (at a later date)?

Thanks

Comment: It means that that particular commit has been made with `Fri Nov 15 12:04:42 2013 +0000`. And it either matches the time when it was actually made, or was specified by a committer manually.

Answer (score 1):

The date means that the commit was done at this date. I.e. information has been added into some place of repository. (With one exception when [--data option](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) was used during commit. In this case the date in git log (which is so called "author date" by default) means the date specified by author when the information was added.)

It could be three ways:

1. The commit has been done into current branch (in your case current means master).
2. The commit has been done into some branch X and then current branch has been created from X branch.
3. The commit has been done into some branch Y and then current branch was rebased onto Y branch.

In case the commit has been done into some branch Z and then Z branch has been merged into current branch you will see the date of the merge, not the date of the commit itself. Since merge is separate commit, which includes all changes (commits) done at the branch Z.

Comment: "The date means that the commit was done at this date" --- no it doesn't. You can specify **any** date you want

Comment: @zerkms, ok, I have added remark about this.